Why is PyTorch Lightning slower than my basic PyTorch code?
I have built a basic model in PyTorch that runs quite fast on my MacBook M2. To improve the structure and readability, I migrated it to the PyTorch Lightning framework. However, I noticed that the computation has become extremely slow, with the number of iterations per second dropping significantly. I can't figure out why this is happening.
I installed the libraries using Poetry, so I just ran poetry add torch and poetry add pytorch_lightning.
Can anyone explain what might be missing in my DataModule, Trainer, or LightningModule that could improve the speed?
data.py
import os
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch import Tensor
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from pytorch_lightning import LightningDataModule

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

from fia.constants import COL_DF_LABEL_FRAUD


class DataFrameDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame, label_column: str):
        """
        Args:
            dataframe (pd.DataFrame): Input data in pandas DataFrame format.
            label_column (str): Name of the column to be used as the labels.
        """

        self.features = dataframe.drop(label_column, axis=1).values
        self.labels = dataframe[label_column].values

        # Convert features and labels to torch tensors
        self.features = torch.tensor(self.features, dtype=torch.float32)
        self.labels = torch.tensor(self.labels, dtype=torch.float32)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.features[idx], self.labels[idx]


class DataModule(LightningDataModule):
    batch_size: int
    random_sate: int
    persistent_workers: int
    num_workers: int

    def __init__(
        self,
        train_df: pd.DataFrame,
        val_df: pd.DataFrame,
        test_df: pd.DataFrame,
        batch_size: int = 32,
        random_sate: int = 42,
        num_workers: int = int(os.cpu_count()*0.8),
        persistent_workers: bool = True,
        prefetch_factor: int = 2,
    ):
        super().__init__()

        self.train_df = train_df
        self.val_df = val_df
        self.test_df = test_df
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_workers = num_workers
        self.random_state = random_sate
        self.persistent_workers = persistent_workers
        self.prefetch_factor = prefetch_factor

        self._class_weights = None
        self.is_data_splitted = False

    def _create_tensor_dataset_from_dataframe(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame):
        return DataFrameDataset(dataframe, COL_DF_LABEL_FRAUD)

    def setup(self, stage: str):

        if stage == "fit" or stage is None:
            self.train_dataset = self._create_tensor_dataset_from_dataframe(
                self.train_df
            )
            self.val_dataset = self._create_tensor_dataset_from_dataframe(self.val_df)

        if stage == "test" or stage is None:
            self.test_dataset = self._create_tensor_dataset_from_dataframe(self.test_df)

    def train_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(
            shuffle=True,
            num_workers=self.num_workers,
            persistent_workers=self.persistent_workers,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            prefetch_factor=self.prefetch_factor,
            dataset=self.train_dataset,
            pin_memory=True
        )

    def val_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(
            dataset=self.val_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            shuffle=False,
            persistent_workers=self.persistent_workers,
            num_workers=self.num_workers,
        )

    def test_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
        return DataLoader(
            dataset=self.test_dataset,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            shuffle=False,
            persistent_workers=self.persistent_workers,
            num_workers=self.num_workers,
        )

module.py
import os
import pandas as pd
from typing import Optional, Any

import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.nn.modules.loss import _Loss
from torch.optim import Optimizer, Adam
from torchmetrics import (
    MetricCollection,
    PrecisionRecallCurve,
    Accuracy,
    Recall,
    Precision,
)
from pytorch_lightning import LightningModule


from fia.nn.classifier import FraudDetectionModel


class LightningFraudClassifier(LightningModule):
    model: nn.Module
    metrics: MetricCollection
    critirion: _Loss

    def __init__(
        self,
        model: nn.Module,
        num_classes: int,
        *args,
        metrics: MetricCollection | None = None,
        criterion: _Loss | None = None,
        **kwargs: Any
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        metrics = metrics or self.initialize_metrics(num_classes=num_classes)

        self.metrics = metrics
        self.model = model
        self.critirion = criterion

        self.train_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix="train_")
        self.val_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix="val_")
        self.test_metrics = metrics.clone(prefix="test_")

    def initialize_metrics(self, num_classes: int) -> MetricCollection:

        metrics = MetricCollection(
            {
                "accuracy_weighted": Accuracy(
                    average="weighted", task="binary", num_classes=num_classes
                ),
                "recall_weighted": Recall(
                    average="weighted", task="binary", num_classes=num_classes
                ),
                "precision_weighted": Precision(
                    average="weighted",
                    task="binary",
                    num_classes=num_classes,
                ),
            }
        )

        return metrics

    def forward(self, inputs: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        # print(f"Inputs Shape: {inputs.shape}")
        return self.model(inputs)

    def step(self, batch: tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]):
        inputs, targets = batch
        logits = self.forward(inputs)
        targets = targets.view(-1, 1)

        loss = self.critirion(logits, targets)
        preds = torch.argmax(logits, dim=1)
        probs = torch.softmax(logits, dim=1)

        return loss, preds, probs, targets

    def training_step(self, batch: tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]):
        loss, preds, probs, targets = self.step(batch=batch)
        self.log(name="train_loss", value=loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log_dict(
            dictionary=self.train_metrics(probs, targets), on_step=False, on_epoch=True
        )

        return {
            "loss": loss,
            "preds": preds,
            "probs": probs.detach(),
            "target": targets,
        }

    def validation_step(self, batch: tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]):
        loss, preds, probs, targets = self.step(batch=batch)
        self.log(name="val_loss", value=loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log_dict(
            dictionary=self.val_metrics(probs, targets), on_step=False, on_epoch=True
        )

        return {
            "loss": loss,
            "preds": preds,
            "probs": probs.detach(),
            "target": targets,
        }

    def test_step(self, batch: tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]):
        loss, preds, probs, targets = self.step(batch=batch)
        self.log(name="test_loss", value=loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log_dict(
            dictionary=self.test_metrics(probs, targets), on_step=False, on_epoch=True
        )

        return {
            "loss": loss,
            "preds": preds,
            "probs": probs.detach(),
            "target": targets,
        }

    def configure_optimizers(self) -> Optimizer:
        return Adam(self.parameters())

trainer.py
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

import torch
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer, seed_everything
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import Callback, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import MLFlowLogger, TensorBoardLogger


from fia.nn.model import FraudDetectionModel
from fia.nn.data import DataModule

from typing import List, Tuple


class TrainerManager:
    def __init__(
        self,
        pl_model: FraudDetectionModel,
        pl_datamodule: DataModule,
        run_datadir: str = "./model_trainer",
    ):

        self.pl_model = pl_model
        self.pl_datamodule = pl_datamodule
        self.run_datadir = run_datadir

        self._logger = MLFlowLogger(
            experiment_name="FraudDetection",
            tracking_uri=f"{self.run_datadir}/mlflow",
            run_name=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%h%M"),
        )

        self._callback_list = [
            EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=4, mode="max"),
            ModelCheckpoint(
                dirpath=Path(self.run_datadir, "checkpoints"),
                filename="{epoch}-{val_loss:.2f}",
                monitor="val_loss",
                mode="min",
                save_top_k=1,
            ),
        ]
        self.trainer = None

    @property
    def logger(self) -> TensorBoardLogger:
        return self._logger

    @property
    def callback(self) -> List[Callback]:
        return self._callback_list

    @classmethod
    def set_seed(cls, seed: int = 42):
        seed_everything(seed=seed)

    def initialise_logger(self):

        tensor_board = TensorBoardLogger(
            save_dir=self.run_datadir, name="FraudDetectionLogs"
        )

        mlflow_logger = MLFlowLogger(
            experiment_name="FraudDetection",
            tracking_uri=self.run_datadir / "mlflow",
            run_name=datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%h%M"),
        )

        return [mlflow_logger, tensor_board]

    def train(
        self, epochs: int = 10, use_gpu: bool = False
    ) -> Tuple[FraudDetectionModel, dict]:

        self.set_seed()

        self.trainer = Trainer(
            logger=self.logger,
            callbacks=self.callback,
            max_epochs=epochs,
            num_sanity_val_steps=0,
            check_val_every_n_epoch=1,
            devices="auto",
            accelerator="gpu" if use_gpu else "cpu",
            accumulate_grad_batches=1,
        )

        self.trainer.fit(model=self.pl_model, datamodule=self.pl_datamodule)

        return self.pl_model, self.trainer.logged_metrics

    def test(self):

        if self.trainer is None:
            raise ValueError("The model has not been trained, Please call train first")

        results = self.trainer.test(dataloaders=self.pl_datamodule, ckpt_path="best")

        return results

model.py

from torch import nn


class FraudDetectionModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(FraudDetectionModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 128)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(128)  # Batch normalization after first layer
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)  # Batch normalization after second layer
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)  # Dropout with 50% probability

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.bn1(self.fc1(x)))
        x = self.dropout(x)  # Apply dropout after activation
        x = self.relu(self.bn2(self.fc2(x)))
        x = self.dropout(x)  # Apply dropout after activation
        x = self.fc3(x)  # No activation function here (output is logits)
        return x

Can anyone help me ?
